# React: How to pass State value to another component and use it to render a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I hope everyone is doing well.

So I have a Hamburger component inside of a Toolbar component that's inside of LandingPage component. I have a state hook inside of the Hamburger component. I am passing down the value of the state to the LandingPage component by using props through Toolbar and eventually to the LandingPage component.
I then have a ternary operator inside of my  sections in my LandingPage component to display a new component (called NavigationMenu) when it's true and not display it when its false.
When I click the hamburger menu, I can see that the boolean value is being passed up to the LandingPage constant via. console.logging, but the ternary operator seems to not dynamically update the boolean value and not render the Navigation Page.

https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-cache-kqfz9

Above is the working code of the hamburger bar. You can see in the console that the value being passed down to the LandingPage is being updated, but the ternary operator (at the BOTTOM of the LandingPage.jsx) is not loading the navigation page.

LandingPage jsx:

```
import React from 'react'

import Toolbar from './Toolbar'
import NavigationMenu from './NavigationMenu'

function LandingPage(props) {

const burgerStatus = []

return (
  <div className='landing-container' >
    <Toolbar burgerStatus={burgerStatus} />

    {burgerStatus[0] ? <NavigationMenu /> : null}
  </div>
)
}

export default LandingPage
```

Toolbar.jsx:

```
import React from 'react'
import Hamburger from './Hamburger'


function Toolbar(props) {
return (
    <div className='navbar' >
      <Hamburger burgerStatus={props.burgerStatus} />
    </div>
)}

export default Toolbar
```

Hamburger.jsx:

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import './Hamburger.scss'


function Hamburger(props) {

  const [burgerClick, setBurgerClick] = useState(true)

  props.burgerStatus[0] = burgerClick


  function clickBurger() {
    setBurgerClick(prev => {
      return (!burgerClick)
    })  

    if (burgerClick === true) {
       props.burgerStatus[0] = true
       console.log(props.burgerStatus[0])
    } else {
      props.burgerStatus[0] = false
       console.log(props.burgerStatus[0])
    }
  }



  return (
    <div className="hamburger" onClick={clickBurger} >
        <div className="line1"></div>
        <div className="line2"></div>
        <div className="line3">
          <div className="blankLeft"></div>
          <div className="line3-right"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

  )
}


export default Hamburger
```

I've included the code above.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can create a working example on codesandbox?

Comment: Hello, I've updated the code to simplify so it only includes the hamburger menu with corresponding files that have been mentioned in the text above.

Comment: Include the code here but also the link to codesandbox. We don't want the codesandbox code to change and a year from now someone finds this question perfectly represents their issue but there isn't any code. Take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for the other rules.

Comment: Hello, I've added the code in the text. I apologize, I'm fairly new to stackoverflow. Thank you for your input! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to SO.

In regards to your issue. You seem to updating props inside the child component. Props pass from parent to child.

```
<LandingPage burgerStatus> => <Toolbar burgerStatus={burgerStatus} /> => <Hamburger burgerStatus={props.burgerStatus} />
```

In the Hamburger component you're doing

```
  const [burgerClick, setBurgerClick] = useState(true)

  props.burgerStatus[0] = burgerClick
```

In react updating data in the parent is done using callback functions. [See this](https://medium.com/@ruthmpardee/passing-data-between-react-components-103ad82ebd17)

**Child to Parent — Use a callback and states**

- Define a callback in my parent which takes the data I need in as a parameter.
- Pass that callback as a prop to the child (see above).
- Call the callback using this.props.[callback] in the child (insert your own name where it says [callback] of course), and pass in the data as the argument.

So I  would have

```
  const [burgerClick, setBurgerClick] = useState(true)
```

in the parent ( `<LandingPage>` ) and pass it as props to Hamburger.

`<Hamburger burgerStatus={props.burgerStatus} setBurgerStatus={props.setBurgerClick} />`

In  Hamburger you can have `<button onClick = {props.setBurgerClick(true)}/>` or `<button onClick = {props.setBurgerClick(false)}/>` on a button click. Since this updates props in he parent, the props should pass down correctly.

Also take a look at this. [Props are read only](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#props-are-read-only)

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your answer. This worked perfectly. But how can I prevent the LandingPage.jsx to prevent full re-rendering whenever i click the hamburger menu? I'm aware whenever a state value is changed, the component re-renders. But I've heard some callbacks such as evt.preventDefault is able to prevent re-rendering and I've tried it, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I would use `shouldComponentUpdate(nextState) { if( this.state.burgerClick !== nextState.burgerClick){return false;} };` This would prevent the re-render on state change. I wouldn't recommend this unless you're gonna have a lot of logic inside `<Landinpage />` which would be a heavy load. React is quite efficient in rendering elements so it shouldn't be a problem to re-render on state change.  Good example - https://lucybain.com/blog/2017/react-js-when-to-rerender/